# mysql scope procedure sub

Tags: mysql, scope, procedure

I am trying to create a procedure where I figure out some interest rate prices and such. Here is a little excerpt.

However, I get an error that says: check the syntax near 'call due_form( in amtDue double, in extPrice double '

Are the variables not in the correct scope? What could be the issue? Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
    create procedure due_form(in amtDue double
                            , in extPrice double
                            , in discAmt double
                            , in discPrice double
                            , in p_taxRate double
                            , out   p_msg   varchar(255))
    begin
        set p_msg := concat(
    'Amount Due         ' , amtDue , '\n'
    , 'Ext Price        ', extPrice, '\n'
    , 'Disc Amount      ', discAmt, '\n'
    , 'After Discount   ', discPrice, '\n'
    , 'Sales Tax        ', p_taxRate);

    end;
    #
    create procedure due( in p_price double
                        , in p_quantity integer
                        , in p_discRate double
                        , in p_taxRate double
                        , in p_shipping double
                        , out p_amtDue  double
                        , out p_msg varchar(255) )
    begin
declare extPrice double;
declare discAmt double;
declare discPrice double;
declare amtDue double;
declare msg varchar(255);

select p_price, p_quantity, p_discRate, p_taxRate, p_shipping;

set extPrice := p_price * p_quantity;
set discAmt := extPrice *  p_discRate; 
set discPrice := extPrice - discAmt; 
set amtDue:= discPrice * p_taxRate + p_shipping;

set p_amtDue := amtDue;

set msg := call due_form( in amtDue double
                                    , in extPrice double
                                    , in discAmt double
                                    , in discPrice double
                                    , in p_taxRate double
                                    , out p_msg varchar(255) )

set p_msg := msg; 

select p_msg;
```

end;

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the result of a procedure to a variable, but `p_msg` will contain a return value since it has the `out` keyword in front.
When you call a procedure, you must not use `in/out`, nor repeat the type of each parameter. The procedure is already defined.

```
select p_price, p_quantity, p_discRate, p_taxRate, p_shipping;

set extPrice := p_price * p_quantity;
set discAmt := extPrice *  p_discRate; 
set discPrice := extPrice - discAmt; 
set amtDue:= discPrice * p_taxRate + p_shipping;

set p_amtDue := amtDue;

call due_form(amtDue, extPrice, discAmt, discPrice, p_taxRate, p_msg );

select p_msg;
```